# How can I fix the blur that is generated with "transform scale"

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter, blur

I have a problem that I've been dragging for a few months which I can't fix since all the "solutions" I find don't work for me, the problem appears when I change the scale of my DIV element. Everything becomes pixelated and the letters are practically not appreciated. I have not been able to replicate the problem, I don't know if it is because it is a very big project or because it can happen, but if anyone has any ideas they would help me a lot. Thank you for considering and reading my problem. Below I leave a screenshot comparing the two cases.

[image]